# Фильтр пользователей в .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod_rewrite, protocol

День добрый! Подскажите, как в `.haccess`'е запретить доступ, отфильтровывая пользователей по определенному протоколу? Т.е. например, если `user` заходит на `https://` то отредиректить его на `http://` (далее тот же `URI`). Знаю один способ через `cgi`, но это как из пушки стрелять по воробьям. :-)

Может кто-нибудь знает способ по-проще? Буду рад помощи.

Answer (score 1):

```
Чтобы перенаправить с HTTPS на HTTP :

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Странно, у меня почему-то не выходит. Выдает ошибку:
`ssl_error_rx_record_too_long`

Comment: попробуйте в настройках *VirtualHost*,*NameVirtualHost* прописать порт.